# installation on SQL Server 2019 Developer fails

Tags: sql-server

I downloaded the file SQL2019-SSEI-Dev.exe and ran it.
I chosed media-download as well as user-defined. In both cases I got the same result.
I chosed german and english. In both cases I got the same result.
The installation-package could be downloaded without problems.
Then when it starts the installation assistent I got this message box.

[image]

I installed SQL Server Express before without problems. Before the installation of the Developer-Edition I deinstalled the Express.

I tried it several times but I am out of ideas now.

Windows Version:
[image]

net framework version:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>msbuild -version
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 4.8.4084.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

4.8.4084.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>

Comment: You best bet is asking this on Microsoft support forums. You can also look for installation log file and check it.

Comment: What version of Windows are you on? SQL Server 2019 requires at least Windows Server 2016 or Windows 10 as well as .NET Framework 4.6.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning And a *maximum* version of Windows 10 or Server 2019

Comment: I put the versions to the question.